# PyQt5: Labels cut off top and bottom in grid layout

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add labels to a dialog window through a for loop. Optimally I would like for the row height to adjust to the content, so that if the string is one line, the row is one line high whereas if the string is 5 lines, the row reflects that. This way I could add a scroll bar to go through all the content.

Instead I get this weird chop-off on the top and bottom of each label:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
window.setLayout(grid)

window.setFixedWidth(200)
window.setFixedHeight(600)

for label in range(5):
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    label.setText(2 * "This is a label with slightly too much text for this little window. Therefore it would be great to wrap this text and have the row size be adjusted automatically.")
    label.setWordWrap(True)
    grid.addWidget(label)

    label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    label2.setText(2 * "HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA")
    label2.setWordWrap(True)
    grid.addWidget(label2)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Outcome when I run program

[image]

Regarding comments about fixed width/height, this is the outcome with fixed width & height commented out:

[image]

Comment: "I get this weird chop-off on the top and bottom of each label". Well, you set both a fixed width and height for the dialog, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I get the same problem even without the fixed width and height. Only in a bigger window.

Comment: That's another story: see [Layout Issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues)

Comment: you must delete this row I think ==> window.setFixedWidth(200)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a QScrollArea:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

window = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWidget(widget)
grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)

window.setFixedWidth(200)
window.setFixedHeight(600)

for label in range(5):
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    label.setText(2 * "This is a label with slightly too much text for this little window. Therefore it would be great to wrap this text and have the row size be adjusted automatically.")
    label.setWordWrap(True)
    grid.addWidget(label)

    label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    label2.setText(2 * "HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA HABALABOBA")
    label2.setWordWrap(True)
    grid.addWidget(label2)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```